# Is there a tool/simulator that supports line coverage for SystemVerilog classes?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have some self-testing code for my SystemVerilog component and I want to ensure that my tests cover everything, especially the failure cases in my classes. All I need is line/branch coverage, just like what is normally used for other object oriented languages such as Java.

I tried using VCS (version 2012.06) coverage, and I found it only has a limited support for SystemVerilog, and does not support any coverage for SystemVerilog classes. Is there any simulator or tool that has this support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2012/08/25

Until further notice, the answer is:

No, there is no tool/simulator that supports line coverage for SystemVerilog classes.

Comment: That is no more true. See my answer on this thread. Questasim 10.2 support the code/line coverage  for SystemVerilog classes.

Answer (score 2):

The Certitude tool by SpringSoft (just purchased by Synopsys) is a tool which checks the effectiveness of your testbench.  It essentially analyzes coverage of your testbench code and does a whole lot more.

http://www.springsoft.com/products/functional-qualification/certitude

Comment: From looking over the Certitude web page, it seems the main feature of Certitude is to inject faults into the RTL and make sure the your testbench catches those faults. In my case, I do not have any RTL (except some empty RTL placeholder files) -- my component is all SystemVerilog. I'm looking to ensure that my SystemVerilog tests for my SystemVerilog component classes cover everything.

Comment: @Victorb: You are correct.  Certitude assumes you have an RTL design; I don't think it can help you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought [Modelsim's](http://www.mentor.com/products/fv/multimedia/using-code-coverage-modelsim-webseminar/) or [Aldec's](http://www.aldec.com/en/solutions/functional_verification/code_coverage/) coverage would do what you need.  To be honest, it looks like [VCS](http://www.synopsys.com/Tools/Verification/FunctionalVerification/Pages/VCS.aspx) does too, so maybe the other tools have the same flaws?

Comment: What do you mean by "VCS does too"? I ran with their line coverage and my SystemVerilog classes weren't covered. Also, I looked into their coverage documentation, which specifically said that coverage for SystemVerilog classes is not supported.

Comment: What I meant was that the link I gave "implied" full "coverage of coverage", in much the same way as the Aldec and Modelsim ones do, so it might be that they don't do what you need either.  Sorry, I wasn't very clear!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that new feature in Mentor **Questasim simulator**. They have implemented SV (systemverilog) class code coverage from Modelsim/Questa 10.2 on.

To activate that feature in a **systemverilog file/class** you need to:

Example :

```
   vlog +cover my_design.sv
   vsim –voptargs=+acc  –coverage  mydesign
```

[image: screenshot_sv_class_ethernet_driver]

vcover may take the following specifications .When no specification is mention , +vcover  is equivalent with “+vcover=bcesft”.

b — Collect branch statistics.

c — Collect condition statistics. Collects only FEC statistics, unless -coverudp is specified.

e — Collect expression statistics, Collects only FEC statistics, unless -coverudp is specified.

s — Collect statement statistics.

t — Collect toggle statistics. Overridden if ‘x’ is specified elsewhere

x — Collect extended toggle statistics .This takes precedence, if ‘t’ is specified elsewhere.

f — Collect Finite State Machine statistics.

Comment: I have a question. What the meaning of 'Xb' with red color in the gui.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [covered](http://covered.sourceforge.net/), but didn't use it myself. It's open source, that's a plus, but seems not to be in development since 2010... :-/